# MySql query for showing records that have two or more same parameters

Tags: mysql

I have a table :

```
#tabel barang
kdgudang  | kdbarang | stok |
g01         a01         12
g01         a02         25
g02         a01          5
g01         a03          7
```

All i want is showing the `kdbarang` that has `kdgudang`=`g01` and `g02`, so the result is `kdbarang` `a01`. 
Can someone tell me what's the query to show it? 
The query that i want is **not**

```
SELECT * FROM barang WHERE kdbarang = 'a01'
```

But some query like

```
SELECT * FROM barang WHERE kdgudang = 'g01' and kdgudang = 'g02'
//it doesn't work, it returns zero result
```

Comment: What do you mean _"and"_? Is it "any of g01, g02"?

Comment: @Alma Do : No, it means 'and'. if 'any of..' i can use 'OR' in query

Comment: Instead of `and` use `or`..

Comment: What records then should be returned? I.e. which column must group your records so you'll be able to check if both values appears across that group?

Comment: @Alma Do : I have said that the result i expected is `a01` that has `g01` and `g02` in `kdgudang` colomn

Answer (score 2):

It's what I have done. it returns what i expected :

```
Select distinct kdbarang from barang 
where kdgudang = 'g02' and kdbarang in (
SELECT distinct kdbarang FROM barang where kdgudang = 'g01'
)
```

If you have the same case with me, may be it helps

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 SELECT * FROM barang WHERE (( kdgudang = 'g01' or kdgudang = 'g02') and kdbarang = 'a01');
```

Comment: yes it will give you result where it get 'g01' or 'go2' for kdgudang

Comment: are you wants kdbarang ='a01' only ?

Comment: ya, i want the result is 'a01'. but not as your query, your query is same as "select * from barang where kdbarang = 'a01'"

Comment: It's what i am expecting :  show all the kdbarang that exists in both warehouse/kdgudang g01 and g02

Comment: SELECT * FROM barang WHERE (( kdgudang = 'g01' or kdgudang = 'g02')  then this query enough.... what is the problem?.. and if it is not same for you then your question is not clear so

Comment: yes, i predicted that my question won't be understandable and easily to be understood. but i have my answer

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to retrieve a specific field then mention the specific field name instead of `*`(which returns all the fields).

Try this:

```
SELECT kdbarang  FROM barang WHERE kdgudang = 'g01' or kdgudang = 'g02';
```

Comment: may be i have to tell you about the 'things' :D

Comment: and prefix `kd` is kode that means `code` in english. so the kdgudang is warehouse code (foreign key, primary key of warehouse table).

Comment: So, the story is : I want to show all the kdbarang that exists in warehouse g01 and g02

Comment: the above solution will return `a01` and `a03`...is that what you are looking for?

Comment: ya, but `a03` is not exists in `g02`

Comment: and if  `a03` is exists in `g02` it returned too. and so the other kdbarang

Comment: It's what i am expecting :  show all the kdbarang that exists in both warehouse/kdgudang g01 and g02

Answer (score 0):

you could also try in

```
SELECT kdbarang  
FROM barang 
WHERE kdgudang in ('g01','g02')
GROUP BY kdbarang 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT kdbarang ) > 0
```

Try it with out the having first you should see them all add the having should remove them.